# TypeError: Cannot set property &#39;user&#39; of undefined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at [file path] sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, express-session

I am receiving an undefined error when attempting to set a session for the user upon validation of credentials on login. I am trying to use express-session to create the session for the user but do not have it directly imported into the file (I was guided to not do so) but am unsure how to resolve this error given. Any help and insight would be much appreciated!

End point:

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body

        // * checks for record existence in db, assigns record to var for access
        const user = await users_access.findByFilter({ username })
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'invalid crededentials' });
        }

        // * compares the entered password to the hash on record 
        const passwordValid = await secure.compare(password, user.password)

        // * handling invalid responses + creating session

        if (!passwordValid) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'invalid credentials' });
        }

        req.session.user = user

        res.json({ message: `welcome, ${user.username}!`})

    } catch(error) { 
        next(error) 
    }
});
```

application model:

```js
// * add users to the datbase
// * inserts argument into user table in db access 
// * returns a user found by id
const add = async (user) => {
    const [id] = await database_access("users")
        .insert(user)
    return findById(id)
}

// * find user record with username and password 
const find = () => {
    return database_access("users").select("id", "username")
}


// * find user by filter 
const findByFilter = (filter) => {
    return database_access("users")
        .select("id", "username", "password")
        .where(filter)
        .first()
}


// * find user with id
const findById = (id) => {
    return database_access("users")
        .select("id", "username")
        .where({ id }) // desctructuring id from the request 
        .first()
}

module.exports = { 
    add, 
    find,
    findByFilter,
    findById
}
```

if you need to see any additional code to assess I am happy to provide but believe this is the source of issue per the error response. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

so I guess you are using the `express-session` module in your entry file for the server, `app.js`, `server.js`, `index.js` however you call it.

this login handler require to be used in a context where the session is available.

I think what you want is not a unit test for this particular router, but an integration test, to test this router in the context of your app.

This is all I can see from the information you provided. If this was not helpful enough, maybe you can show us your servers main file. and how this router is used.